# Discrete Math: Counting Problem with balls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

1. A bowl contains 10 red balls and 10 blue balls.A woman
   selects balls at random without looking at them.

a) How many balls must she select to be sure of having
at least three balls of the same color?

b) How many balls must she select to be sure of having
at least three blue balls?

We went over this example in class and apparently the answer to the part a is 5 and part b is 13. I understand part b because if she had to worst luck in the world and chose all 10 of the red balls she would need 13 selections to make sure she gets the 3 blue balls.

I don't understand part a. Couldn't she just be really lucky s and elect 3 red/blue balls on her first 3 selections? Even if she chose 5 balls couldn't she just choose 5 reds/blue balls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$4$ balls is not enough, because you could draw two blue and two red balls. $5$ balls is enough, because (by the pigeonhole principle) you will always have at least $3$ red or at least $3$ blue balls.

If we divide five object in two groups, one group contains at least half of the objects (since they cannot both contain strictly less than half of the objects). A group cannot contain $\frac 52$ objects, so one group must contain at least $3$ object.

Comment: How do you know by the pigeonhole principle there will be at least 3 red or blue balls?

Comment: @ComicStix, (just in case you didn't notice), I edited the post a while ago.

Answer (score 0):

If she gets $5$ blue then she gets *at least* $3$ blue.